# postgres pg_xlog explodes during set tablespace

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6, tablespaces, write-ahead-logging

I'm running postgreSQL 9.6.0 on CentOS 7.2. Occasionally I need to shift data on to a larger tablespace to prevent `/var` from filling up. When this is running the `pg_xlog` directory grows rapidly, and recovers very slowly. Periodic `CHECKPOINT`'s subsequently help to kick the xlog clean up into action. However, this laborious  severely limits the amount of data I can shift in a short space of time. Upgrades and restarts are very tricky since the database records continuous long running collections from various data sources.

My gut feeling is that `SET TABLESPACE` prevents updates from WAL being committed, but this doesn't make much sense...

Any help or insight greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you move a table to a new table space and your wal_level is above "minimal", then the entire contents of the table are copied to the WAL stream.  That is why pg_xlog grows quickly.  Shrinking slowly could simply be because your archive_command can't keep up, and WAL files can't be removed until they are archived if archiving is on.  What are your settings for wal_level, archive_mode, and archive_command?

Comment: Hi @jjanes - thanks! I'm running a warm standby so:
`wal_level = replica`,
`archive_mode = on`, and
`archive_command = 'rsync -a %p [privatedbserver]:/var/lib/pgsql/9.6/backup/%f'`
Is there anyway around that? I know it's recommended to keep WAL on a separate , reasonably sized partition...

Comment: Can you tell if rsyncing the WAL file is a bottleneck?  But if you have stringent uptime requirements, I think your only real solution is to avoid needing to do `set tablespace` in the first place.  For example, use a storage system that can dynamically resize disk arrays and partitions.